# AWS CloudFormation + Elastic Beanstalk single instance: delete the default EIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, elastic-ip

I am in the process of automating our deployment on AWS through CloudFormation.

My template is creating a few Elastic Beanstalk environments in `SingleInstance` mode, in order for them to then be accessed through a single Application Load Balancer which is created separately.

By default, creating an EB environment in `SingleInstance` mode results in a new Elastic IP Address being created and attached to the instance. This is not needed in my setup, as the instances are going to be accessed through the ALB.

I couldn't find any configuration option that would stop EB from creating and associating these EIPs, therefore my only option seems to be manually disassociating and releasing them after the EB environments have been created (through the AWS console or the CLI).

Is there a way to automate this step within CloudFormation templates?

I have looked into CloudFormation's configuration sets but I don't think they fit my need, as every command set there would run within the EC2 instance which, by default, should not be able to make changes to my whole AWS environment.